# Bundle command the wrong mysql2 gem (always 0.3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, mysql2

I got an error when trying to run $rails console

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2.rb:8
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler.rb:112:in `require'
    from /Users/ccool2486/Sites/test3mysql/config/application.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:21:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:21
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
ccool-2:test3mysql ccool2486$ rails console
WARNING: This version of mysql2 (0.3.2) doesn't ship with the ActiveRecord adapter bundled anymore as it's now part of Rails 3.1
WARNING: Please use the 0.2.x releases if you plan on using it in Rails <= 3.0.x
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:71:in `establish_connection': Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter) (RuntimeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:59
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:1903
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:32
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `to_proc'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/railtie.rb:180:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/railtie.rb:180:in `load_console'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/application.rb:154:in `load_console'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:11:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:11:in `all'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/application.rb:154:in `load_console'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:26:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:23
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

Hmm... so i tried to uninstall the mysql2 gem, and reinstall the version 0.2.7 gem

```
 sudo gem uninstall mysql2 -i /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
```

And I changed the gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2','0.2.7'
```

Ran Bundler in my app directory:

```
bundle install
```

**But it installed the version 0.3.2 back again!!! Can anyone help, I honestly don't know what happened here.**

Comment: Same issue here - broken my app. I'm beginning to seriously dislike Bundler. It's annoying that it automatically updates gems without asking. There must be a way to prevent this. Will see what I can do, if I find a solution I'll post back here.

Comment: Thanks, the answer to this question is a model for a 100 other fixes I'll need to make in the future.

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo gem uninstall mysql2
```

in Gemfile `gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'`

```
bundle update
```

Answer (score 0):

with your

```
gem 'mysql2','0.2.7'
```

Try

```
bundle update
```

it builds the bundle from scratch